# Angular add commas directive on keyup keeping original value as int

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a directive called add-commas that I want to add commas to inputs.  However, I want it to do that without the rest of my code having to clean those commas out.  So instead I am trying to have the directive hide the current input and create a new input.

So my goal is to create a new input making the original input hidden.  Then the new input has a keyup event which will add commas for its own value (for the user to see) but then strip the commas and update the value of the original hidden input.  This way for my ng-model variable it always is without commas but for the user they see commas.

But if I tell it to add the input `.after()` the original then on the change of that new input I cannot use `.next()` to get the original element to update its value and there is no `.previous()`.  There is also no `.before()` according to the [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) to allow me to place my element before the original and thus I would be able to use `.next()` to get the original.

```
/**
* Add Commas Directive
* @namespace Directives
*/
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('MyApp')
    .directive('addCommas', addCommas);

/**
 * @namespace addCommas
 * @desc Directive for adding commas to text inputs
 * @memberof Directives
 */
function addCommas($compile) {

    return {
        link: link
    };

    function link(scope, el, attrs) {
        hideThisInput(el);

        var newInput = createNewInputFromOriginal(el);
        clearInputClass(el);

        // Format value 
        newInput.bind('keyup', function () {
            // Remove previous commas
            var val = newInput.val().replace(/\D/g, '');

            // Add the new commas
            newInput.val(val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
            newInput.parent().find('input[type="hidden"]').val(parseInt(val));
        });
    }

    function hideThisInput(element) {
        element.attr('type', 'hidden');
    }
    function createNewInputFromOriginal(element) {
        var newInput = angular.element('<input type="text" class="' + element.attr('class') + '"/>');
        element.after(newInput);
        $compile(newInput);
        return newInput;
    }
    function clearInputClass(element) {
        element.attr('class', '');
    }

}
}());
```

Comment: Why don't you make use of element.parent if understand your problem correctly. Moreover one suggestion have a look at angular formatters https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$formatters

Comment: Using parent would then require using a find on the element as far as I am aware and a parent is limited in the find to tag name only from what the Angular documentation says.  So I cannot use parent and then find a [type=hidden] input but only an input.